# FRP Huawei P9 Lite with Voice keyboard only

Tags: factory-reset, google, huawei, 7.0-nougat

I have recently just installed the Huawei P9 Lite Nougat beta update (EMUI 5 Update) and, when I wanted to setup the phone, I needed to do the FRP Verification (Which I can't because I have the voice keyboard only)
Does anyone know the bypass for this or maybe a solution? Thank you!
P.S. It is the test keys version.

Comment: The ROM doesn't have a keyboard??

Comment: This seems to work [FRP Huawei P9 Bypass with select text method and Google Assist.](https://wn.com/huawei_bypass_google_account_p9)

Answer (score -1):

I just used this keyboard, dictating my data by letters, then i opened the Google play and downloaded a normal gboard. That wass really hard, but i did it.

Comment: This may be an answer. I think Pon meant that they used Voice Assist to do the FRP verification by sending instructions letter by letter and once past that, they used Play Store to install normal keyboard app to replace Voice assist.